# Elasticsearch must_not inside nested query

Tags: elasticsearch

My elastic search index having nested fields. and I want to use must, which contains a must_not query in it with a nested query. I have tried a must_not query separately in the following way:

```
{
    "bool": {
        "must_not": [{
            "nested": {
                "path": "fields",
                "query": {
                    "terms": {
                        "fields.value.raw": [
                            "200"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

above query gives me a valid result but when I was tried this with must query then it will not give me any result.I am using following query:

```
{
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "nested": {
                    "path": "fields",
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [{
                                "match": {
                                    "fields.uid": "number"
                                }
                            }, {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must_not": [{
                                        "nested": {
                                            "path": "fields",
                                            "query": {
                                                "terms": {
                                                    "fields.value.raw": [
                                                        "200"
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }]
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
```

above query not gives me a valid result. What is wrong in above query?
How I can use a must_not in must with nested query?

Comment: It would help if you wrote a sentence or two describing what you want the query to do. For example, I want all documents where price equals 10.

Comment: my nested schema as follows:
{
 "fields": {
  "type": "nested",
  "properties": {
   "uid": {
    "type": "keyword"
   },
   "value": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
     "raw": {
      "type": "keyword"
     }
    }

   }
  }
 }
}


so I want documents having fields.uid is the number and the value of number field(fields.value) does not contain "200 " so need to add must_not in must, How I can get the valid result?

Answer (score 2):

You should use must and must_not in the same bool query.

```
{
    "bool": {
        "must_not": [{
            "nested": {
                "path": "fields",
                "query": {
                    "terms": {
                        "fields.value.raw": [
                            "200"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }],
        "must": [{
            "match": {
                "fields.uid": "number"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: above query not giving me a valid response I want to check and query with the following condition for nested objects:

documents having fields.uid is number and the number does not contain "200 "

so need to add must_not in must, How I can get the valid result?